# Making a Bootstrap label clickable in a Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, razorengine

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap Label clickable, using Razor syntax.

```
@Html.ActionLink("<span class=\"label label-danger\">" + @item.P1slared + "</span>", "queue", new { id = item.P1slared + "/" })
```

However it appears on my screen as below:

[image: ScreenShot]

Is there anyway I can make it output the actual label as a clickable link, similar to below:

[image: Screen Shot as it should show]

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you Use @Url.Action Instead of Html.ActionLink. Like this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("queue","ControllerName", new { id = item.P1slared })"><span class="label label-danger">@item.P1slared</span></a>
```